# Ubuntu 18.04 lag after kernel downgrade 5.3->4.4

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on kernel 5.3 but for some testing purpose with real time kernel I have to downgrade to 4.4.

After downloading and installing the 4.4 kernel, I booted into it and everything is super laggy. I tried figuring out what is the problem but I did not find anything useful, I also tried installing it different ways from different tutorials but that did not change anything (I tried fresh install each time). If I then again boot into 5.3 kernel, everything is fine.

I noticed that in 4.4, the Xorg seems to be taking quite a lot of CPU %. Should I downgrade it or?

Any input on the topic is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that your newer kernel has additional graphics APIs that your newer userland is taking advantage of and that your older kernel does not.  In addition, Ubuntu may have backported additional APIs that are required that your older kernel does not have.

As a result, your graphics may not be accelerated (or may be only partially accelerated), and if you're using a desktop that uses OpenGL or Vulkan APIs, some or all of the operations may be being done on the CPU, which is far, far slower.

In general, if you're using a certain version of Ubuntu, you'll need to use its kernel or a newer upstream one, and possibly a much newer upstream one, for good performance.  In fact, unless you are an advanced user and cognizant of what you're doing, you're far better off using the distro kernel.  Downgrading to an older kernel, like you're doing, isn't going to work.  Consider using a virtual machine for testing instead.

Comment: Thank you for the info, this is what I was afraid of, that it is probably some API issue with graphic display. However the thing is not actually happening in VM, I haven't had lag issues until I put it on real hardware, guess VM is emulating graphics in different way so different thing is used or the intel HD graphics . 
The X server seems to be doing what you mentioned using CPU to do graphic stuff which causes the lag, when I scroll some window the CPU usages goes up and it lags sometimes for up to 1-2 seconds.

Comment: VM graphics are a fake video card that uses a special pass-through driver, so you don't have this problem.  If you need to test with your 4.4 RT kernel, do _that_ in a VM.

Comment: I tried on different real systems and on 1 I am getting lag one 2nd I am not getting. What I noticed is that it is not recognizing the graphics card, what it is used is llvmpipe instead Intel HD graphics. Probably driver missing or not supporting the hardware.
But digging deeper I noticed even more issues, there seems to be issue with network drivers also, it is not working correctly, can not get internet to work. The usage of cpu is also super high, 100% with firefox only running, as if it is only using 1 core of CPU.

Comment: Okay, I think my point is that you can't downgrade the kernel to a version older than that provided by the distro and expect things to work.  There are lots of things that could be broken and if you need to use an older kernel, then you need an older distro.